# Dealing with very large Lists on x86

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to work with large lists of floats, but I am hitting memory limits on x86 systems. I do not know the final length, so I need to use an expandable type. On x64 systems, I can use `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`.

My current data type:

```
List<RawData> param1 = new List<RawData>();
List<RawData> param2 = new List<RawData>();
List<RawData> param3 = new List<RawData>();

public class RawData
{
    public string name;
    public List<float> data;
}
```

The length of the paramN lists is low (currently 50 or lower), but data can be 10m+. When the length is 50, I am hitting memory limits (`OutOfMemoryException`) at just above 1m data points, and when the length is 25, I hit the limit at just above 2m data points. (If my calculations are right, that is exactly 200MB, plus the size of name, plus overhead). What can I use to increase this limit?

**Edit:** I tried using `List<List<float>>` with a max inner list size of 1 << 17 (131072), which increased the limit somewhat, but still not as far as I want.

**Edit2:** I tried reducing the chunk size in the List> to 8192, and I got OOM at ~2.3m elements, with task manager reading ~1.4GB for the process. It looks like I need to reduce memory usage in between the data source and the storage, or trigger GC more often - I was able to gather 10m data points in a x64 process on a pc with 4GB RAM, IIRC the process never went over 3GB

**Edit3:** I condensed my code down to just the parts that handle the data. http://pastebin.com/maYckk84

**Edit4:** I had a look in DotMemory, and found that my data structure does take up ~1GB with the settings I was testing on (50ch * 3 params * 2m events = 300,000,000 float elements). I guess I will need to limit it on x86 or figure out how to write to disk in this format as I get data

Comment: And your  questions is...?

Comment: `hitting memory limits` as in getting something like an `OutOfMemoryException`? And 200MB is how much you expect each item inside each List takes up?

Comment: The list capacity resizing algorithm doubles the size of the holding array when the limit is reached. This can prove hugely inefficient. Is it possible to anticipate the final length of any of your lists and thus supply a capacity at construction? If any of your lists are hanging around for any appreciable length of time without modification, you should consider using `.TrimExcess()`, but beware that a single addition after `.TrimExcess` will cause a doubling of capacity.

Comment: Yes, I am getting an OutOfMemoryException. 200MB was `4B * (50 elements in paramN list) * (1048576 data points)`. I know the number of elements in the param lists (they dont often change), and sometimes have an idea of the number of data points, but I am continuously adding data points and it could easily go over

Comment: You shouldn't be hitting a memory limit at 200MB. Unless your system is low on resources to begin with, that is really small...Can you not run a profiler and monitor your program?

Comment: You need to use a data structure that stores its data in something other than pure contiguous data (the `List<T>` uses an array internally).  You may want to create a custom data structure that creates new arrays as existing ones fill up, daisy chaining them like a linked list.  The .Net `StringBuilder` does this since .Net 4.0 or 4.5, so you can look at its source code for an example.

Comment: Your code example does not sufficiently illustrate the precise problem. In general, you may hit the limit in size of a `List<T>` before you run out of memory, and you can work around that by creating a data structure as e.g. a `List<List<T>>` (i.e. a list of lists). But on x86, you will always be strictly limited to relatively small amounts of data (3GB is the theoretical max, but in practice the actual limit can be as low as 1.2-1.4GB). Provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reliably reproducing the problem if you want an actual answer.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with @Gjeltema. Sometimes GC can struggle to find big contiguous blocks of memory while there's plenty of the stuff hanging around in smaller fragments.

Comment: You haven't said how you're loading the data, and what you're doing with it - do you need it all in memory or can you just process chunks?

Comment: I receive the data over a socket, and it is eventually saved to a file in a format that makes it a little difficult to save if you dont know the full size beforehand

Comment: @MalikDrako - Can you please update your question with the code that you're using to read the socket, process the data, and to save the results?

Comment: Its quite a bit of code, should I post it here, or is there somewhere else that would be better to host it?

Comment: @MalikDrako - Thanks for posting the code. However, when I go to copy it to LINQPad it's just laden with errors. There must be quite a bit of code missing. When you provide code it must be complete. We can't be expected to "mind compile" all that code. Can you try putting it on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and get it to the point where it compiles at least?

Comment: I would suggest to store your data on the disk. What about using TeaFiles.net ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, on x86 systems memory limit is 2GB, not 200MB. I presume 
your problem is much more trickier than that. You have aggressive LOH (large object heap) fragmentation. 
CLR uses different heaps for small and large objects. Object is large if its size is larger than 85,000 bytes. LOH is a very fractious thing, it is not eager to return unused memory back to OS, and it is very poor at defragmentation.
.Net List is implementation of ArrayList data structure, it stores elements in array, which has fixed size; when array is filled, new array with doubled size is created. That continuous growth of array with your amount of data is a "starvation" scenario for LOH. 
So, you have to use tailor-made data structure to suit your needs. E.g. list of chunks, with each chunk is small enough not to get into LOH. Here is small prototype:

```
public class ChunkedList
{
    private readonly List<float[]> _chunks = new List<float[]>();
    private const int ChunkSize = 8000;
    private int _count = 0;       

    public void Add(float item)
    {            
        int chunk = _count / ChunkSize;
        int ind = _count % ChunkSize;
        if (ind == 0)
        {
            _chunks.Add(new float[ChunkSize]);
        }
        _chunks[chunk][ind] = item;
        _count ++;
    }

    public float this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if(index <0 || index >= _count) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            int chunk = index / ChunkSize;
            int ind = index % ChunkSize;
            return _chunks[chunk][ind];
        }
        set
        {
            if(index <0 || index >= _count) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            int chunk = index / ChunkSize;
            int ind = index % ChunkSize;
            _chunks[chunk][ind] = value;
        }
    }
    //other code you require
}
```

With `ChunkSize` = 8000 every chunk will take only 32,000 bytes, so it will not get into LOH. `_chunks` will get into LOH only when there will be about 16,000 chunks in collection, which is more than 128 million elements in collection (about 500 MB).

**UPD** I've performed some stress tests for sample above. OS is x64, solution platform is x86. ChunkSize is 20000.

First:

```
var list = new ChunkedList();
for (int i = 0; ; i++)
{
    list.Add(0.1f);
}
```

OutOfMemoryException is raised at ~324,000,000 elements

Second:

```
public class RawData
{
    public string Name;
    public ChunkedList Data = new ChunkedList();
}

var list = new List<RawData>();
for (int i = 0;; i++)
{
    var raw = new RawData { Name = "Test" + i };
    for (int j = 0; j < 20 * 1000 * 1000; j++)
    {
        raw.Data.Add(0.1f);
    }
    list.Add(raw);
}
```

OutOfMemoryException is raised at i=17, j~12,000,000. 17 RawData instances successfully created, 20 million data points per each, about 352 million data points totally.

Comment: @HungPV, It's just a prototype to show how to organize memory. Anyway, implementing editability is definitely gonna be painful (imagine item being removed in middle of collection of 1 million elements, 1 op on deletion, 500k operations on moving elements; LinkedList is bad for memory footprint and locality; probably sophisticated system of multi-level chunking and dislocation maps is the way). However, I don't think OP is in need of editing collection, it seems to be simple storage for raw data to use in numeric analysis

Comment: I tried reducing the chunk size in the List<List<float>> to 8192, and I got OOM at ~2.3m elements, with task manager reading ~1.4GB for the process.

Comment: @MalikDrako, Note that chunk is `float[ ]`, not float. In standart implementation of List there are no chunks, just initial capacity for continiously growing array. I've performed stress test for implementation above and with ChunkSize = 20000 I recived OOM at ~324m elements at x86 configuration. Can try to switch `List<float> data` in RawData to `ChunkedList data` with ChunkedList implementation from above?

Comment: That helped a bit, but I think I'm hitting total process memory limits, since I'm getting OOM exceptions in other places. I added the code relevant to data handling in the question

Comment: @MalikDrako, next candidate is other collections. How large is pendingDataRcv? Also, if behavior is reproducible, you can pause program execution slightly before OOM and look with memory analyzer (such as https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) on structure of heaps and what objects retain memory.

Comment: For this test, I was sending 60400B/packet, and that list was 80000 capacity. I'll give that memory analyzer a try

Comment: I had a look in DotMemory, and found that my data structure does take up ~1GB with the settings I was testing on (50ch * 3 params * 2m events = 300,000,000 float elements). I guess I will need to limit it on x86 or figure out how to write to disk in this format as I get data

Comment: @MalikDrako, so the bottleneck is located. I  suggest you to extend your  RawData with ability to save float data to temp file and load it back - in that case you can simply use BinaryReader/BinaryWriter. Aside from that, it seems the case is closed:)