# An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in .dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, out-of-memory

I have a table in sql server with
rows count: 1229502
columns count: 56
TotatlSpaceInKB : 292616

When I fetch the full table and fill DataTable in C# it gives a 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
So I decided to fetch table in 2 chunks and fill 2 different DataTables, which worked.

But according to requirements I have to store all data in List ,
Unfortunately storing both DataTables in same List gives Exception.
Conversion of one table to list go smooth but when I store second table in same list it gives error.

I'm converting the DataTable to List through the following code

```
//CC_Data is DataTable
//CC_List is List<Cent_Compilation>
//Cent_Compilation is class with same properties as in Database
foreach (DataRow row in CC_Data.Rows)
                {
                    Compilation_Methods.CC_List.Add(Compilation_Methods.populateClassObject(row, CC_Data));
                }
```

populateClassObject is method for conversion

```
public static Cent_Compilation populateClassObject(DataRow row, DataTable table)
        {
            using (Cent_Compilation CC = new Cent_Compilation())
            {
                try
                {
                    PropertyInfo[] columns;

                    Type myType = (typeof(Cent_Compilation));
                    columns = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                    object data = null;
                    foreach (var column in columns)
                    {

                        if (table.Columns.Contains(column.Name))
                        {
                            data = DBSupport.ExtractData(row, column.Name);
                            if (data != null)
                            {
                                column.SetValue(CC, DBSupport.FindNReplaceDataType(data, column.PropertyType), null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    //Log.Add("Error in Method populateClassObject Class Inter_Data" + ex.Message);
                }

                return CC;
            }
        }
```

This is what the exception looks like:

[image]

Comment: Are you building your code in 64bit? This will allow you to allocate significantly more memory for your application. This won't address underlying issues of using huge amounts of memory but it should alleviate the out of memory error. I've loaded 8gb of data into a list before by compiling my software in 64bit.

Comment: @NibblyPig Anyway, it's weird that he has the exception in the `Cent_Compilation` constructor. Can you decompile it?

Comment: @NibblyPig this is an organization's Application they want me to build it in 32 bit,,,

Comment: @Brainiac I suspect your memory is dissappearing because of how a List allocates memory... especially if the objects in the list are 85k+ it gets allocated as a Large Object on the Heap and is a bit cumbersome... Also Lists in essence are an ArrayList which have a fixed size... when adding items, if you reach the boundary it will cause a new list double the size to be created... Have a look at this chunked list solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486475/dealing-with-very-large-lists-on-x86

Comment: @MatteoUmili same exception but with different dll name (System.Data.dll) occured when i was storing all data in directly in one DataTable

Comment: @PaulZahra correct me if i am wrong,,, you want me to make nested list or list with items of array type with fixed length???

Comment: Problem is simple: you can't load all that data at once. Solutions: More memory or manage data differently, clearly you can't have all the records in a list... And I would like to know why would you need to have it in memory everytime

Comment: @Brainiac No no... I am just pointing out that you use a List (List<Cent_Compilation>) which is not efficient at storing large amounts of potentially large data (you don't explain how big your objects are)... you instantiate the List, it's size 1... you add an item CC_List.Add()... List is recreated at double size (it's now size 2)... you add another... it doubles again size 4... and again size 8... and again size 16... and again size 32... etc etc and again 500,000, and again 1m etc etc... very innefficient eh?

Comment: @Brainiac The accepted answer of the linked post is only a prototype but the essence of it is sound (keep your list away from the Large Object Heap by keeping it on the Small Object Heap)... i.e. stop lists going near 85k in size, this way they do not get put on the Large Object Heap, which is inefficient and doesn't like to give up it's memory (made worse by the way that Lists create a new arraylist of double the size once you add an item that breaks it's current arraylist boundary).

Comment: @Brainiac so chunking is a solution if your lists are going over 85k which I suspect they are... have a read of this ... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshwil/2005/08/10/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit/